# How can I crop image with the Croppie plugins to a size proportional to the indicated one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a symfony project where I have to show news with some image. The image will be displayed in 3 parts with different measures, one in the news with normal size (600x400px), another in the news list with a small size (130x130px) and another in the notation list of the rectangular form (700x200px).

The images fit the different sizes, but the problem is that the rectangular image to have low height and much width only appears a part of the original image and cuts the rest. So the user uses the plugins to search the image of the right size and adjust the part that is visible, scrolling the image and zooming of the plugins.

So everything is perfect, the problem I have is that I want to crop the large image to the size described (600x400px), but to show me the plugin a smaller proportional image when it comes to trimming.

That is, I have the following code to use the plugin:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$uploadCrop = $('#upload-demo1').croppie({
  enableExif: true,
  viewport: {
      width: 600,
      height: 400,
      type: 'square'
  },
  boundary: {
      width: 700,
      height: 500
  }
 });

 $('#upload').on('change', function () { 
   var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
     $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
       url: e.target.result
     }).then(function(){
     });
    }
   reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
 });


 $('.upload-result').on('click', function (ev) {
   $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
     type: 'canvas',
     size: 'viewport',
     format:'jpeg'
  }).then(function (resp) {
    $.ajax({
     url: Routing.generate('image_create'),
     type: "POST",
     data: {"image":resp},
     success: function (data) {
       html = '<img src="' + resp + '" />';
       $("#upload-demo-i").html(html);
     }
   });
 });
});
```

**PHP**

```
public function imagen_createAction()
 {
    $data = $_POST['image'];
    list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
    list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    $time=time();
    $imageName = $time.'-p.jpeg';
    $photoDir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web/uploads/news/';

    file_put_contents($photoDir.$imageName, $data);

    return new JsonResponse(array(
        'message' => 'Success!',
        'success' => true), 200);
}
```

Where you can see a limit of 700x500 and the frame for the image of 600x400, and saving it creates the cropped image of that size. But I do not have enough space to show that size when editing (700x500), so I would like to know if the container can be displayed with a proportional measure, so that when generating the cut image is saved as I want to 600x400.

I'm new to this, so I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolved this problem by changing:

> size: 'viewport',

to

> size: { width: 700, height: 200 },